# How to preserve nginx url from being redirected from back end tomcat server?

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

Nginx is not preserving the url from redirected backend tomcat server.

Nginx url: //develop-application.example.com/

Backend tomcat url:  //application.example.com/

tomcat redirected url:  //application.example.com/application

I want the client browser url to always remain https://develop-application.example.com/ no matter what returns from tomcat.

Config:

```
server {
        listen 443 proxy_protocol;
        set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
        real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/develop-application.example.com.https.access.log elb_log;

        server_name develop-application.example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt.chained;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        location / {

            proxy_pass https://application-ssl/;
            proxy_redirect default;
            # proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        }
    }

upstream application-ssl {
          server application.example.com:443 weight=100;
          least_conn;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`proxy_redirect default` does not work when an `upstream` label is employed. You will need to make your rule explicit, such as:

```
proxy_redirect https://application.example.com/ https://develop-application.example.com/;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for the full syntax.

Comment: Good call. Should have mentioned that I spent a half day on this and I used the aforementioned proxy_redirect in several attempts.  I did follow the document you mentioned, but assumed I was doing pass through instead of reverse proxy, because it will not keep the url.

Comment: I've attempted both methods noted here.  Thx btw.  They both work fine for apache applications, but they both redirect to the original application in tomcat and drop the develop- in https://develop-applcation.example.com.